# using apply to calculate across rows and columns

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, apply

I have searched long and hard for a solution using apply but I am unable to find exactly what I need.  I'm a new R user comming over from Excel and need to calculate the percent difference from an observation with a control.  A realistic sample data frame looks like this:

```
site <- c(rep(1, 10), rep(2,10), rep(3,10))
element <-rep(c("ca", "Mg", "K"), 10)
control <- seq(from= 1,to=60, by=2)
BA01 <- seq(from= 31,to=90, by=2)
BA02 <- seq(from= 21,to=80, by=2)
BA03 <- seq(from= 101,to=160, by=2)
mydf <- data.frame(site, element, control, BA01, BA02,BA03)
```

where BA01 to BA03 are different test which will be compared to the control.

all I would like to do, is make a formula like this:
((BA01-control)/control)*100

and have it calculated for every test column(BA01-BA03) and every row in the data frame.  In Excel I could just copy and paste the site and element columns plus the headers BA01-BA03 the type the formula in cell C2  and drag the formula to the right as far as needed then down as far as needed and have my results.  In R I'm having difficulty getting the same results.  I've tried apply already but can not get it to work.  Basically, I would like to have Site and Element as columns 1 and 2, followed by the results from the formula with BA01, BA02 and BA03 as the column names. Probably it wouldn't make a difference, but my real data frame will have upwards of 130 columns and several thousand rows.

Does anyone have some tips for me?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
cbind(mydf[1:2],sapply(mydf[-(1:3)],function(x) 100*(x-mydf[[3]])/mydf[[3]]))
   site element       BA01       BA02       BA03
1     1      ca 3000.00000 2000.00000 10000.0000
2     1      Mg 1000.00000  666.66667  3333.3333
3     1       K  600.00000  400.00000  2000.0000
4     1      ca  428.57143  285.71429  1428.5714
5     1      Mg  333.33333  222.22222  1111.1111
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cbind(mydf[1:2], 100 *  mydf[4:6] / mydf$control - 100)
```

The first 5 lines of output are:

```
   site element       BA01       BA02       BA03
1     1      ca 3000.00000 2000.00000 10000.0000
2     1      Mg 1000.00000  666.66667  3333.3333
3     1       K  600.00000  400.00000  2000.0000
4     1      ca  428.57143  285.71429  1428.5714
5     1      Mg  333.33333  222.22222  1111.1111
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
pdiff <- function(x,y) (x-y)/y*100
BAcols <- subset(mydf,select=c(BA01,BA02,BA03))
```

This `subset` is readable for a small data frame but if you really have lots of rows you want to normalize you will want to select these columns by using a numeric range, i.e. `mydf[,-(1:3)]` (drop the first three columns) or `mydf[,4:ncol(mydf)]` (keep columns 4 until the end).

```
cbind(mydf[,1:2],sweep(BAcols,1,mydf$control,pdiff))
```

or

```
 with(mydf,data.frame(site,element,sweep(BAcols,1,control,pdiff)))
```

Comment: thank you both very much for the reply!  Both solutions work very well and give exactly what I need, now I just have to do my homework so I can understand the functions in R better but at least now I can get back to work and successfully skip exporting my results into excel and go directly from the database into R. I do have a question for James though. How come you use two [] in the sapply command? I tried out using [3] and it worked, however I'm sure there is a reason why you recommend [[3]], why is that?